# Cross-site request forgery validation failed required param state missing from persistent data

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying cross domain fb login using graph API.

[image]

I am getting error "Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data"

**Step 1 Code:**

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
              'app_id'                => $this->appId,
              'app_secret'            => $this->appSecret,
              'default_graph_version' => $this->apiVersion,
    ]);

    $permissions = [
                    'email',                        
                    'manage_pages', 
                    'business_management',
                    'ads_management'
                    ];

    $helper    = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginUrl  = $helper->getLoginUrl($this->redirectUrl.'?back_to='.$customer_website_url, $permissions);
```

**Step 3 Code**

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => $appId,
  'app_secret'            => $appSecret,
  'default_graph_version' => $graph_api_version,
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

Everything I have explained in Image so anyone what can be the problem and possible solution?

Comment: `state` parameter is stored in the session, when the login URL is created. So the redirect back to the app from Facebook must go to the same domain, because that’s where the session is.

Answer (score 1):

First check whether your PHP script is encoded with **UTF8 or **UTF8 without BOM**. Sometimes this causes problem, it may occur because of some other reasons also one of them is **SESSION handling**. I get this error when I try back and forward button in browser :D

**Step 3** will be callback php script shared in Fb APP where **Facebook** will redirect the user after taking **Fb App permissions**. If it is different or domain is different you may get this.

You can also set `state` parameter manually.

Try this

In your **step 3 Code**, after getting **Access Token**, convert it to long-lived token, set **Access Token** in session and check for **GET** parameter which you're passing based on that redirect to the page

```
$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'                => $appId,
  'app_secret'            => $appSecret,
  'default_graph_version' => $graph_api_version,
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

if (!$accessToken->isLongLived()) {
    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    try {
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
        exit;
    }
}

// You can also store this access token in database for future use
$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

if (isset($_GET['back_to']) and $_GET['back_to'] == '<any_specific_value>') {
    header("Location: <specific page>");
    exit();
} else {
    // User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
    // You can redirect them to a members-only page.
    header("Location: <default page>");
    exit();
}
```

On `<specific page>/<default page>`, using **fb_access_token** from session you can query **Facebook Graph/Marketing Api**

Once this is done and if you're storing **Access Token** in database, in **Step 1 Code**, you can check whether you're already having  **Access Token** of specific user or not.

```
// Query database for Access token of the user

if (exists) {
    // Fetch access Token and use it
} else {
    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
              'app_id'                => $this->appId,
              'app_secret'            => $this->appSecret,
              'default_graph_version' => $this->apiVersion,
    ]);

    $permissions = [
        'email',                        
        'manage_pages', 
        'business_management',
        'ads_management'
    ];

    $helper    = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginUrl  = $helper->getLoginUrl($this->redirectUrl.'?back_to='.$customer_website_url, $permissions);
}
```

Comment: real problem is because of two different domains, I could not get access token on my domain because request was sent from customer's domain.

Comment: Any idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483537/how-to-add-user-to-facebook-custom-audience ?

Comment: the BOM thing was the problem for me