# How to add user to facebook custom audience

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to add user to custom audience using following code

```
$audience = new CustomAudience($custom_audience_id);
$audience->addUsers(array(trim($mailAddress)), CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL);
```

and

```
$users = array(
 array('fname', 'lname', 'someone@example.com'),
 array('fnamenew', 'lnamenew', 'someone_new@example.com'),
);

$schema = array(
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::FIRST_NAME,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::LAST_NAME,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EMAIL,
);

$audience = new CustomAudienceMultiKey(<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>);

$audience->addUsers($users, $schema);
```

But I am getting error in both codes

```
(#2650) Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source EVENT_BASED.WEB_PIXEL_HITS, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS
```

Following code I am using to create custom audience.

```
$audience = new CustomAudience(null, $accountId);
        $audience->setData(array(
          CustomAudienceFields::NAME            => $associative_arr['name'],
          CustomAudienceFields::PIXEL_ID        => $associative_arr['pixelId'],
          CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION     => $associative_arr['description'],
          CustomAudienceFields::RETENTION_DAYS  => $associative_arr['retensionDays'],  
          CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE         => CustomAudienceSubtypes::WEBSITE,
          CustomAudienceFields::RULE            => array('url' => array('i_contains' => $associative_arr['websiteUrl'])),
          CustomAudienceFields::PREFILL         => $associative_arr['prefill'],
          CustomAudienceFields::DATA_SOURCE     => array('EVENT_BASED' => 'WEB_PIXEL_HITS')
        ));         
        $audience->create();
```

Any suggestion how I can solve this?

Comment: When you created empty custom audience object in that did you mentioned this `CustomAudienceFields::DATA_SOURCE => array('EVENT_BASED' => 'WEB_PIXEL_HITS');`. If not then when're creating custom audience you will need to add this as data source and try your code

Comment: This is what helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555810/470749

Answer (score 0):

You can only add user to the custom audience that is created through emails, While the code you shown in creating audience is based on user activities on your website.
You can follow this doc to create your custom audience through email:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api#build

And then in your ads, you can combine the two audience (From emails and/ from