# Data source error while trying to add user in custom audience

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to add user to custom audience using following code

```
$audience = new CustomAudience($custom_audience_id);
$audience->addUsers(array(trim($mailAddress)), CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL);
```

and

```
$users = array(
 array('fname', 'lname', 'someone@example.com'),
 array('fnamenew', 'lnamenew', 'someone_new@example.com'),
);

$schema = array(
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::FIRST_NAME,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::LAST_NAME,
  CustomAudienceMultikeySchemaFields::EMAIL,
);

$audience = new CustomAudienceMultiKey(<CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID>);

$audience->addUsers($users, $schema);
```

But I am getting error in both codes

```
(#2650) Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source EVENT_BASED.WEB_PIXEL_HITS, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS
```

Any suggestion how I can solve this or is there any way I can add user while updating custom audience?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add user to facebook custom audience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483537/how-to-add-user-to-facebook-custom-audience)

Comment: I got `FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException: (#2650) Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source FILE_IMPORTED.MULTI_HASHES, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS. in /var/www/myproject/vendor/facebook/php-business-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Http/Exception/RequestException.php:159` But see https://www.facebook.com/groups/pmdcommunity/permalink/1231872900198509/ The fix: pass a schema array as `$type` in https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/4.0.0/src/FacebookAds/Object/CustomAudience.php#L483

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom audience from only either a Website Traffic(Pixel), App Engagement, Customer file or from Engagement on Fb. If you create an audience from Website traffic (Pixel), you can't add user's to the audience like you can when creating the audience from customer file.